# Prettify GraphQL query string in Java

Tags: java, formatting, graphql, graphql-java

I have a Java program which, among other things, reads raw GraphQL queries from XML files and sends them to a given endpoint via HTTP. The problem is that server accepts only proper formatted GraphQL queries, which means no extra spaces, newlines etc. are allowed. So basically I have to write them in a single line, because any newline symbol will break whole query by adding lots of spaces to match XML hierarchy (element containing query is not root element).

As you can tell, single-lined queries, especially long ones are not human-friendly and they're hard to read. There are a lot of code formatters/prettifyers here and there, online, inside IDEA, Postman, Insomnia etc, all of them can do it in a single button click.

Working XML file (one-lined query):

```
<request>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/graphql</url>
    <type>GRAPHQL</type>
    <body>mutation { login(input: {username: \"user\", password: \"12345\"}) {status}}</body>
</request>
```

Desired XML file (multi-line query):

```
<request>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/graphql</url>
    <type>GRAPHQL</type>
    <body>
        mutation {
          login(input: {username: "user", password: "12345"}) {
            status
          }
        }
    </body>
</request>
```

How can I deal with that scenario? Before sending, I should perform formatting on the 'body' string. Is there any 'prettification' library, or should I write custom symbols 'remover'?

Comment: No GraphQL server should ever care about white space since [the spec explicitly says extra white space is ignored](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-White-Space). Someone could choose to enforce that sort of thing for a particular server, but it's hard to imagine it would be a part of any common implementation. I'm just wondering if this is in fact what's going on, or if you're seeing some sort of error when you send the request and assuming it's formatting related.

Comment: @DanielRearden yeah you're correct about white spaces, they don't matter. The only cause as far as I can tell were `"\n"` symbols, and simple `replaceAll("\n", "")` does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

graphql-java already come with `AstPrinter` that can pretty print a GraphQL AST node. So you can first convert the query string to the AST node and then use it to prettify the query string:

```java
 String gql = "mutation { login(input: {username: \"user\", password: \"12345\"}) {status}}";
 Parser parser = new Parser();
 Document doc = parser.parseDocument(gql);
 System.out.println(AstPrinter.printAst(doc)); //which should print out a prettified query here
```

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!